# Given a positive integer $a_0$, define $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ recursively by $a_i = 1^2 + 2^2 +\cdots+ a_{i-1}^2$ for $i\geq1$.

Tags: combinatorics

Given a positive integer $a_0$, define $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ recursively by $a_i = 1^2 + 2^2 +\cdots+ a_{i-1}^2$ for $i\geq1$. Is it true that, given any subset $A$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, there is a positive integer $a_0$ such that, for $1\leq i\leq n$, $6$ divides $a_i$ if and only if $i\in A?$

I tried to use the formula for sum of squares of first $n$ natural number. But here $a_0$ is arbitrary. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: @GregMartin The recent issue of AMS Monthly Problem 12255. The due date is Sept 30, 2021.

Comment: Ongoing contest. Unlock after due date mentioned in comments.